# Javascript - fluid organic motion of a div element (rotation and translation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pulling my hair out trying to use jquery plugins to create smooth motion with the div elements I'm working with. Time to get some help.

I have a series of div elements that share a class and I'd like them to continuously move around the screen (similar to [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DYN6U/) I found). The methods used in that fiddle work great for Raphael vector graphics - not so much with CSS elements (I, noob that I am, did try).

Here is the really complicated part. I would like to rotate each element so that the "top" of the element always faces the direction of motion. That part is killing me (did I mention I haven't done trig since high school?).

So, how can I rotate and translate a div element as described? I'm already using jquery elsewhere on the page, so I'd prefer to use jquery and not add any other frameworks.

As a note, I have tried [move.js](http://jquery-plugins.net/move-js-css3-javascript-animation-framework), but apparently it only works with absolute translations, not relative, so the first interval moves my element, the second interval it stays put (since it's already X and Y from its starting point). With random translations, it bounces around inside a box. I'm trying [minimit Anima](http://jquery-plugins.net/minimit-anima-jquery-plugin-to-animate-with-transforms-and-transitions) now, but so far it looks to be about the same result. I am using the jquery .each() method to move each element independently (which works fairly well). Where I'm at now is attempting to create a vector (angle and distance) and pass that vector into some trig to give me (relative) translation coordinates.

:edit: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaycenornin/L2UEg/) with just the translation/rotation code I've been working on, using just CSS3 transforms and jquery's .animate(). No luck there either, so I'm broken somewhere. Note: I am just using the webkit transform right now. If I get it working then I'll worry about cross-browser compatibility. The code in the fiddle works in a browser, but doesn't seem to do anything in the fiddle. It makes me cry :( :/edit:

:edit: Removed full code - [the code from the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaycenornin/L2UEg/) should be sufficient :/edit:

```
setInterval('moveMoth()', 100);
var moveX, moveY, moveH, angle;
var i = 0;

function moveMoth() {
    $(".mothwrap").each(function () {
        if (angle) {
            angle = ran(-15, 15) + angle;
        } else {
            angle = ran(-15, 15);
        }
        moveH = ran(20, 60);
        moveX = (Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)) * moveH;
        moveY = (Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)) * moveH;
        $(this).children('.mothdiv').css({
            WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });
        $(this).animate({
            left: '+=' + moveX,
            top: '+=' + moveY
        }, 500);
        $("#mothbox").append("Interval");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally sorted it out.
I think part of my confusion was that the element I wanted to move was moving sideways when I was expecting it to move forwards. It also helped to focus on getting the movement for one right before adding more.

Below is my code. It's still not exactly how I'd like it, but it's good enough :)

```
function moveMoth() {
    // for troubleshooting.
    // if the script is running, this should print to the page
    //$("#mothbox").append("Interval");
    var moveX, moveY, moveH, angle, borderL, borderR, borderT, borderB, posLeft, posTop;
    var position = pageCell.position();
    borderL = position.left;
    borderT = position.top;
    borderR = parseInt(pageCell.width());
    borderB = parseInt(pageCell.height());
    $(".mothwrap").each(function (index,element) {
        var me = $(this);
        angle = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-angle"));
        if (angle) {
            angle = parseInt(ran(-15, 15)) + angle;
        } else {
            angle = parseInt(ran(0, 360));
        }
        posTop = parseInt(me.css("top"));
        posLeft = parseInt(me.css("left"));
        if (posLeft < borderL) { angle = 0;}
        if (posLeft > borderR) { angle = 180;}
        if (posTop < borderT) { angle = 90;}
        if (posTop > borderB) { angle = 270;}
        if (angle < 0) { angle += 360;}
        if (angle > 360) { angle -= 360;}
        element.setAttribute("data-angle", angle);
        moveH = ran(2, 6);
        moveX = parseInt((Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * moveH);
        moveY = parseInt((Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * moveH);
        me.children('.mothdiv').css({
            '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
            '-ms-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
            '-o-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',  
            '-ms-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
            'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+angle+')'
        });
        me.css({
            top: '+=' + moveY + 'px;'
        });
        me.css({
            left: '+=' + moveX + 'px;'
        });
    });
}
```